# Oracle Error ORA-28368: cannot auto-create wallet

Tags: linux, oracle, wallet

I'm trying to set up Oracle 11.2.0 XE on a LINUX server and getting an ORA-28368 error.  Research shows I need to create a "wallet" folder and then issue the command as sysdba "alter system set encryption key identified by "my_password" to set the default master password.

I've been able to do this successfully under Windows by creating the folder C:\ora11g\app\oracle\admin\XE\wallet.

I don't use a sqlnet.ora file so I created the wallet folder in the default location /u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/wallet as root and set the permissions to 777, the owner to oracle and group to dba. This location matches the Windows folder structure that worked.

The ORACLE_HOME folder does not have an admin folder by default so I created that and the wallet folder under it as a test but that didn't work either.

Environment variables are:

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

ORACLE_SID=XE

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like I might have a case sensitivity problem.  I noticed the the SID is in upper case but the product installed to a lower case folder "xe".  I solved the problem by creating a sqlnet.ora file and specifying the location of the wallet folder (notice the upper and lower case XE).

```
sqlnet.ora location: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/**xe**/network/admin

sqlnet.ora entry:

ENCRYPTION_WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/u01/app/oracle/admin/**XE**/wallet)) )
```